# How can i monitor disk and memory usage in azure linux?

Tags: linux, azure

I am new to azure. I cannot monitor disk and memory usage for a Linux machine in azure. How can I monitor disk and memory usage? Please, anyone, help me regarding this issue.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

- We can check the Linux Memory metrics from Azure Portal
- Navigate to Azure portal => Your VM => Under Monitoring , select Insights

[image]

[image]

- You can also check metrics from the Diagnostics Settings from Portal

Diagnostics Settings => Overview => Pick a storage Account => Enable Guest level Monitoring

- We can enable Guest level monitoring while creating VM

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your Reply @RithwikBojja-MT    Actually while installing I do not enable guest diagnostics and I go to insights also but there is nothing I get. And I need to monitor in grafana. what are possible ways to monitor in grafana. please help me regarding this issue.